# Implementing a single event handler for multiple controls with different event handler delegates

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, validation

I have a function, `void Validate()`, that contains all my validation logic for a window.

I can't simply register this as an event handler because it doesn't accept the parameters required by the event handler delegates. Additionally different types of controls have different signatures so I can't just have `Validate` match one signature while ignoring their contents.

Here is a small example of what I've setup

```
    txt1.TextChanged += Validate_TextChange;
    password1.PasswordChanged += Validate_RoutedEvent;
    txt2.TextChanged += Validate_TextChange;

    txt3.TextChanged += Validate_TextChange;
    password2.PasswordChanged += Validate_RoutedEvent;
    txt4.TextChanged += Validate_TextChange;


void Validate_RoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateOptions();
}

void Validate_TextChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateOptions();
}

public void ValidateOptions()
{
   //Actual validation here
}
```

This just shows 2 examples, more controls could have even more signatures. Is there any better way of getting all event handlers to call a function in a case where I don't care about the arguments being passed?

---

EDIT:
I like the option proposed by Jon to add the parameters and simply ignore them. That does solve most of the problem but anytime I want to call this function directly, such as to manually trigger validation, I then have to include dummy arguments to satisfy the compiler.
    ValidateOptions(this, new EventArgs())

The suggestion Dan made, to use anonymous functions, would handle this but isn't as clean when associating the event handlers.

It doesn't appear that either solution lets you register a function as an event handler while ignoring the signature while also preserving the ability to call the function without creating dummy arguments but there are multiple ways to get pretty close.

---

EDIT:

Here is the updated example implementing Jon's solution for generic event handling but keeping a 0 parameter function that can be called directly

```
txt1.TextChanged += ValidationEvent;
password1.PasswordChanged += ValidationEvent;
txt2.TextChanged += ValidationEvent;

txt3.TextChanged += ValidationEvent;
password2.PasswordChanged += ValidationEvent;
txt4.TextChanged += ValidationEvent;


//Single event handler accepting EventArgs, which is the base class
//for all more-specific event classes
void ValidationEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Ignores arguments and calls 0 argument ValidateOptions
    ValidateOptions();
}

//0 argument function that performs actual validation and can be called
//directly from other functions without the need to pass in a fake sender
//and eventargs parameter
public void ValidateOptions()
{
   //Actual validation here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* have a single method which ignores the parameters:

```
public void ValidateOptions(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The compiler will allow a conversion from the `ValidateOptions` method group to *any* delegate type following the normal event pattern such that the first parameter is `sender` and the second parameter is some type derived from `EventArgs`.

Comment: Even the signature `void (object, object)` would work actually.

Comment: @H.B.: True - I'd prefer to make it obvious it's there for event handling though :)

Comment: @Jon I like this, and it did work, but I then realized that I neglected part of the use case in my original question (updated). One reason the Validate() function didn't already do this is because I wanted to call it to force validation from other functions and with this approach I simplify the event handler usage but have to use fake values when calling it directly.

Comment: @Eric: Just make that single method call a parameterless one, then you can use the parameterless one elsewhere, but use this for all event handlers.

Comment: @Jon So while my original example had 3 (1 without parameters, 2 with different event handler signatures) I would end up with 2 (1 without parameters, 1 with generic event handler signatures that calls the 0 parameter version, which I can also call directly). The benefit is that I'll always have exactly 2 no matter how many different control types I need to implement. Sound right? I think that is the best-possible hybrid solution

Comment: @Eric: Yup, that's what I reckon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use lambda expressions to reduce the amount of code you write for wrappers, though, behind the scenes, it's still creating wrapper methods to discard the parameters.

```
txt3.TextChanged += (s,e) => ValidateOptions();
password2.PasswordChanged += (s,e) => ValidateOptions();
txt4.TextChanged += (s,e) => ValidateOptions();
```

Answer (score 0):

This handler provides a single callback for framework controls and the argument 'e' is preserved for consumption...

```
    private static void EventHandlerSink(object sender, dynamic e) 
    {

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to use `dynamic` when all event arguments inherit from `EventArgs`, you just loose the little interface you had left when boxing it to that.